# Pregunta innerWidth & innerHeight

Tags: javascript, método

Hola buenas no me sale que el tamaño de la pantalla vaya cambiando cuando redimensiono la pantalla

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <title>Práctica</title>
 <meta charset="UTF8"/>
</head>
<body>

 <p>El ancho de la pantalla es de <span id="anchoPantalla">XXXXXX</span> píxeles</p>
 <p>El alto de la pantalla es de <span id="altoPantalla">XXXXXX</span> píxeles</p>


 <script>
window.onresize = function(e) {

  let ancho = e.innerWidth;
  let alto = e.innerHeight;

  console.log(ancho);
  console.log(alto);
  document.getElementById('anchoPantalla').textContent = ancho;
  document.getElementById('altoPantalla').textContent = alto;

 }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza el objeto `window` directamente para obtener las dimenciones `innerWidth` y `innerHeight` ya que el parametro `e` no tienen esas propiedades:

```js
window.onresize = function(e) {

  let ancho = window.innerWidth ;
  let alto = window.innerHeight;

  console.log(ancho);
  console.log(alto);
  document.getElementById('anchoPantalla').textContent= ancho;
  document.getElementById('altoPantalla').textContent = alto;

 }
```

```html
<p>El ancho de la pantalla es de <span id="anchoPantalla">XXXXXX</span> píxeles</p>
 <p>El alto de la pantalla es de <span id="altoPantalla">XXXXXX</span> píxeles</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar window.innerHeight y width respectivamente, ademas puedes usar un onload para que te carga directamente los width y el height cuando se carga la pagina.

aqui un ejemplo. Espero te ayude

```js
window.onresize = function(e) {

  let alto = window.innerHeight
|| document.documentElement.clientHeight
|| document.body.clientHeight

  let ancho = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;;

  console.log(ancho);
  console.log(alto);
    
    
 var x = document.getElementById("anchoPantalla");
x.innerHTML = ancho;

 var y = document.getElementById("altoPantalla");
y.innerHTML = alto;

 }
  
  
  window.onload = function(e) {

  let alto = window.innerHeight
|| document.documentElement.clientHeight
|| document.body.clientHeight

  let ancho = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;;

  console.log(ancho);
  console.log(alto);
    
    
 var x = document.getElementById("anchoPantalla");
x.innerHTML = ancho;

 var y = document.getElementById("altoPantalla");
y.innerHTML = alto;

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <title>Práctica</title>
 <meta charset="UTF8"/>
</head>
<body>

 <p>El ancho de la pantalla es de <span id="anchoPantalla">XXXXXX</span> píxeles</p>
 <p>El alto de la pantalla es de <span id="altoPantalla">XXXXXX</span> píxeles</p>


</body>
</html>
```